# Firestore replying entire document changeset/history

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have two cloud functions, when a user authenticates with my frontend web app, it sets a flag on the user object, this triggers the first cloud function to execute:

```
exports.observeUserUpdate = functions.firestore
    .document("/data/{uid}")
    .onUpdate(async (snapshot) => {
      const user = snapshot.after.data() as User;

      if (user.scanRepositories) {
        await pubSubClient
            .topic("user-repositories-update")
            .publish(Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(user)));
      }
    });
```

This function will send a topic to a queue where I have a subscriber that will pick up that message and perform some backend operations, modifying nested documents under the user.

I have a second cloud function that is listening for changes under the user document, but only acting on changes that I'm interested in:

```
exports.observeRepositoryUpdate = functions.firestore
    .document("/data/{uid}/repositories/{repositoryId}")
    .onUpdate(async (snapshot) => {
      const repository = snapshot.after.data() as Repository;

      if (repository.task == null || repository.task.length == 0) {
        return;
      }

      if (repository.task.some((task: Task) => task.run)) {
        await pubSubClient
            .topic("repository-update")
            .publish(Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(repository)));
      }
    });
```

When documents change and meet a certain condition it will fire off another topic for a different backend system to process.

This is all pretty straightforward and makes sense, where things are going wrong is the user is signing out and when they sign back in, and a flag is set, rightfully the first function triggers and the backend does what it is supposed to, however, all the messages that were sent as part of the second function, are being "replayed" to the consumer of that subject.

For example, the user logs in and creates `tasks` for the `repositories`. Those tasks are correctly executed and everything is working as it should. The user then logs out, and then back in, and those same tasks are fired again by the second function when they shouldn't be.

It looks like the second function is firing the entire changeset/history.

Is my data structure just wrong, or are my document paths incorrect? Would love some help and apologies this was very wordy.

edit: To help illustrate here is the sequence in the server logs of what's happening

```
// User logs in, login task fires as expected
2021-10-28 12:12:27.489  INFO 60338 --- [pool-1-thread-2] s.f.g.listeners.consumer.UserConsumer    : User consumer triggered: User(uid=g1OQ0K1...)
2021-10-28 12:12:27.492  INFO 60338 --- [pool-1-thread-2] s.f.github.services.GitHubServiceImpl    : Finding repositories
2021-10-28 12:12:31.954  INFO 60338 --- [pool-1-thread-2] s.f.g.r.FirestoreRepositoryImpl          : Batch write for 131 repositories
2021-10-28 12:13:05.827  INFO 60338 --- [pool-1-thread-2] s.f.g.r.FirestoreRepositoryImpl          : Batch write for 9 languages
2021-10-28 12:13:05.829  INFO 60338 --- [pool-1-thread-2] s.f.g.r.FirestoreRepositoryImpl          : Batch write for 5 types
// Login task complete 

// User runs task on repository
2021-10-28 12:13:50.392  INFO 60338 --- [pool-1-thread-2] s.f.g.l.consumer.RepositoryConsumer      : Repository consumer triggered: RepositoryDto(id=39931...)
2021-10-28 12:13:51.237  INFO 60338 --- [pool-1-thread-2] s.f.g.s.PackageManagerServiceImpl        : Detecting package manage for google-photo-frame with language Java
2021-10-28 12:13:52.319  INFO 60338 --- [pool-1-thread-2] s.f.g.r.FirestoreRepositoryImpl          : Batch write for 1 package managers
// Task completes

// User logs out and back in, the RepositoryConsumer is triggered again when it shouldnt
2021-10-28 12:15:09.917  INFO 60338 --- [pool-1-thread-5] s.f.g.l.consumer.RepositoryConsumer      : Repository consumer triggered: RepositoryDto(id=39931...)
2021-10-28 12:15:10.807  INFO 60338 --- [pool-1-thread-5] s.f.g.s.PackageManagerServiceImpl        : Detecting package manage for google-photo-frame with language Java
2021-10-28 12:15:11.872  INFO 60338 --- [pool-1-thread-5] s.f.g.r.FirestoreRepositoryImpl          : Batch write for 1 repositories
2021-10-28 12:15:12.262  INFO 60338 --- [pool-1-thread-5] s.f.g.listeners.consumer.UserConsumer    : User consumer triggered: User(uid=g1OQ0K1...)
2021-10-28 12:15:12.262  INFO 60338 --- [pool-1-thread-5] s.f.github.services.GitHubServiceImpl    : Finding repositories
2021-10-28 12:12:31.954  INFO 60338 --- [pool-1-thread-2] s.f.g.r.FirestoreRepositoryImpl          : Batch write for 131 repositories
2021-10-28 12:13:05.827  INFO 60338 --- [pool-1-thread-2] s.f.g.r.FirestoreRepositoryImpl          : Batch write for 9 languages
2021-10-28 12:13:05.829  INFO 60338 --- [pool-1-thread-2] s.f.g.r.FirestoreRepositoryImpl          : Batch write for 5 types
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/replay-overview#subscription_message_retention):

> By default, subscriptions discard messages as soon as they are acknowledged. Unacknowledged messages are retained for a default of 7 days (configurable by the subscription's message_retention_duration property).

Therefore it seems strange that messages are being replayed if it has been acknowledged by the second function, but it also states that:

> Configuring a subscription to retain acknowledged messages (via the `retain_acked_messages` property) lets you replay previously-acked messages sent to the subscription. Messages in a subscription can be retained for a maximum of 7 days, whether they are acknowledged or unacknowledged. In other words, the age of the oldest message in a subscription will not exceed 7 days.

This could explain the behaviour you are having when a user signs out and signs in again, the tasks are fired again.

As in this [GitHub repo](https://github.com/googlearchive/pubsubbeat/blob/master/pubsubbeat.yml) states how it behaves depending on the `retain_acked_messages`flag:

```yaml
# Whether to retain acknowledged messages. If true, acknowledged messages
# will not be expunged until they fall out of the RetentionDuration window.
  subscription.retain_acked_messages: false
```

Also in the part [Seeking to a snapshot](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/replay-overview#seek_to_a_snapshot) states that:

> Once a snapshot is created, it retains:
>
> - All messages that were unacknowledged in the source subscription at the time of the snapshot's creation.
> - Any messages published to the topic thereafter.
>
> You can replay these unacknowledged messages by using a snapshot to seek any of the topic's subscriptions.

To avoid that behavior I would recommend configuring the `retain_acked_messages`flag as best works for you and also use [filters](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/replay-overview#seeking_with_filters):

> You can replay messages from subscriptions with filters. If you seek a timestamp using a subscription with a filter, the Pub/Sub service only redelivers the messages that match the filter.
> A snapshot of a subscription with a filter contains the following messages:
>
> - All messages that are newer than the snapshot, including messages that do not match the filter.
> - Unacknowledged messages that are older than the snapshot.